# How to check the life of the wallet address?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to know if there is a way to check how long ago is the wallet created? like 2 days ago, 6 months ago?

Is there a way we can check?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you have to check something "close" to that is to actually look for the oldest tx timestamp at which the address of the wallet made/received a transaction.

That said, it doesn't mean that is as old as this transaction interaction.
You can check that by simply putting the address in [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/)

If you happen to have the Keystore associated JSON to the wallet (unlikely unless you created it), they're usually generated setting the name of the file as `timestamp_of_generation_in_UTC+_format.json`.

So from there you can also extract the info.

Answer (score 0):

Like CPereez19 was saying, you would need to query all transaction across all chains you are interested in and then check when the first one took place.

I work at Moralis, and we recently released a wallet activity [endpoint](https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/reference/get-chain-activity-by-wallet) that let's you input a wallet address and get back the date of when the wallet was created (date of first transaction). You can check this across all the chains we support in the same call.

The response would look like this:

```
{
  "address": "0xd8da6bf26964af9d7eed9e03e53415d37aa96045",
  "active_chains": [
    {
      "chain": "eth",
      "chain_id": "0x1",
      "first_transaction": {
        "block_timestamp": "2015-09-28T08:24:43.000Z",
        "block_number": "302086",
        "transaction_hash": "0x9b629147b75dc0b275d478fa34d97c5d4a26926457540b15a5ce871df36c23fd"
      },
      "last_transaction": {
        "block_timestamp": "2023-07-10T08:09:35.000Z",
        "block_number": "17661990",
        "transaction_hash": "0x3c02990e853b3672e535f3509bf4a16d4ab50317b701b74c63cbe684af1793d1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```